# 'File does not exist' when passing a non-ASCII path to xarray.open_dataset

Tags: python, onedrive, python-xarray

I have a problem when attempting to open a .nc file. For my college work I need to work with some data stored on .nc files, so I decided to give the 'xarray' library a go. The files are located on an OneDrive cloud. When passing the 'open_dataset' function a path that contains non-ASCII characters, the following error occurs:

```
    import xarray as xr
    path1 = (r'C:\Users\myname\OneDrive - Prirodoslovno-matematički fakultet'
                 '\DACCIWA\DATA\Sodar\Save_KIT_CM_20160702.nc')
    ds = xr.open_dataset(path1)

    Traceback (most recent call last):

    File "C:\Users\petar\Desktop\Geofizika\5. Godina\KB - Research opportunity\test.py", line 9, in <module>
    ds = xr.open_dataset(path1)

    File "C:\Users\petar\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xarray\backends\api.py", line 499, in open_dataset
    filename_or_obj, group=group, lock=lock, **backend_kwargs

    File "C:\Users\petar\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xarray\backends\netCDF4_.py", line 389, in open
    return cls(manager, group=group, mode=mode, lock=lock, autoclose=autoclose)

    File "C:\Users\petar\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xarray\backends\netCDF4_.py", line 335, in __init__
    self.format = self.ds.data_model

    File "C:\Users\petar\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xarray\backends\netCDF4_.py", line 398, in ds
    return self._acquire()

    File "C:\Users\petar\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xarray\backends\netCDF4_.py", line 392, in _acquire
    with self._manager.acquire_context(needs_lock) as root:

    File "C:\Users\petar\Anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 112, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)

    File "C:\Users\petar\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xarray\backends\file_manager.py", line 183, in acquire_context
    file, cached = self._acquire_with_cache_info(needs_lock)

    File "C:\Users\petar\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xarray\backends\file_manager.py", line 201, in _acquire_with_cache_info
    file = self._opener(*self._args, **kwargs)

    File "netCDF4\_netCDF4.pyx", line 2135, in netCDF4._netCDF4.Dataset.__init__

    File "netCDF4\_netCDF4.pyx", line 1752, in netCDF4._netCDF4._ensure_nc_success

    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'C:\\Users\\petar\\OneDrive - Prirodoslovno-matemati\xc4\x8dki fakultet\\DACCIWA\\DATA\\Sodar\\Save_KIT_CM_20160702.nc'
```

I am confused since the file definitely is there (In the code above I replaced my name in the path with "myname", which does not contain non-ASCII characters). At first I thought this had to do something with OneDrive, but I created a folder on it with a path that does not contain non-ASCII characters, and it opens those no problem.

What I tried (although this was really just shotgunning, not familiar with encodings and such):
- input string as raw string (as you do to escape the slashes)

I noticed in the last line that the string path was preceeded by the letter "b", apparently this means that the string is a "byte literal" and can only contain ASCII characters, in which case why does xarray convert/interpret the string as a byte literal? How would I go about opening the file?
Thanks for help!

Comment: Python as default may use `utf-8` encoding but file system on Windows may use different encoding for filenames - ie. `cp1250`. At least I had this problem with Polish chars in older Windows - but with local files, not in cloud drive.

Comment: @furas, how'd you fixed it (if you did)?

Comment: as I remeber `filename.encode('cp1250')` to get it as bytes. But long time ago I learned to use filenames without native chars and without spaces because both things always made problems - not only in Python but in any other language or program.